# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

My code was compiling before but stopped working and is giving this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

log

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Activity name cannot be empty.      at
>   com.android.tools.idea.model.MergedManifest$ActivityAttributes.(MergedManifest.java:579)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.model.MergedManifest.syncWithReadPermission(MergedManifest.java:418)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.model.MergedManifest.access$000(MergedManifest.java:55)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.model.MergedManifest$1.run(MergedManifest.java:331)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:945)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.model.MergedManifest.sync(MergedManifest.java:328)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.model.MergedManifest.getActivities(MergedManifest.java:464)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.run.activity.DefaultActivityLocator.lambda$computeDefaultActivity$97(DefaultActivityLocator.java:78)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService$1.run(DumbService.java:89)

my manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:header=".MyApplication"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:header=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:header="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:header="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:header=".ui.ResponseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_item_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:header="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ui.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for your main activity because `name` field is required to identify an activity not the `header` so replace every `header` with `name` field

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

instead of this

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:header="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:header="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

So it will

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and do the same for other activities too

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `android:name=".ui.activityName"` in your activity tag of manifest file for each of the activity.

Hope this helps!